# Applying snapshot does not empty reconfiguredItemIdentifiers

Tags: swift, diffabledatasource

I'm using UITableViewDiffableDataSource in my project with UIKit. In some cases (e.g. moving item from one place to another) I need to use `.reconfigureItems(_:)` or `.reloadItems(_:)` to force DiffableDataSource to update certain cells. But the result of using those methods can lead to updating all items in UITableView. I found that when I'm applying snapshot using `.apply(_:)` all the previous items are still in the `snapshot.reconfiguredItemIdentifiers` property.

Here is a code example of setting up UITableViewDiffableDataSource and reproducing the problem.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var activitiesDataSource: [Activity]!
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Activity.ID>()
    
    lazy var diffableDataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Activity.ID>(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        let activity = self.getActivity(by: itemIdentifier)
        print("setting up cell with title: \(activity.title)")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = activity.title
        return cell
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        activitiesDataSource = [Activity(title: "first"), Activity(title: "second"), Activity(title: "third")]
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = diffableDataSource
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        
        prepareSnapshot()
    }
    
    func prepareSnapshot() {
        let activitiesIds = activitiesDataSource.map(\.id)
        snapshot.appendSections([0])
        snapshot.appendItems(activitiesIds)
        diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot)
    }
        
    func getActivity(by id: UUID) -> Activity {
        guard let activity = self.activitiesDataSource.first(where: { $0.id == id }) else {
            fatalError("Could not find activity by id")
        }
        return activity
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let activityId = snapshot.itemIdentifiers[indexPath.row]
        let activity = getActivity(by: activityId)
        activity.title += " tap"
        snapshot.reconfigureItems([activityId])
        diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot)
    }
}
```

---

And `Activity` class looks like:

```
class Activity: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

If you tap first, second and third cells, the output will be kind of:
setting up cell with title: first tap
setting up cell with title: first tap
setting up cell with title: second tap
setting up cell with title: first tap
setting up cell with title: second tap
setting up cell with title: third tap

While I was expecting to have:
setting up cell with title: first tap
setting up cell with title: second tap
setting up cell with title: third tap

Can someone help me and explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new snapshot from the previous one instead of directly updating the property-stored one as it's.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

> You can create and configure a snapshot in one of these ways:
> Create an empty snapshot, then append sections and items to it.
> Get the current snapshot by calling the diffable data source’s snapshot() method, then modify that snapshot to reflect the new state of the data that you want to display.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var snapshot = diffableDataSource.snapshot()

        let activityId = snapshot.itemIdentifiers[indexPath.row]
        let activity = getActivity(by: activityId)
        activity.title += " tap"
        snapshot.reconfigureItems([activityId])

        diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot)
    }
```

Hopefully this solves your problem, if not then also consider having your model `Activity` conform to `Identifiable and Hashable` instead of using the `UUID` directly as hashable.

```swift
...
lazy var diffableDataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Activity>(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
...
```

If it persists, adding your own version of the `Equatable` method `==(lhs:rhs)` may help the diffing algorithm properly identify your cells.

```swift
static func ==(lhs: WeekAnime, rhs: WeekAnime) -> Bool {
        // Your comparable condition.
        // like lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Btw `Hashable` already conforms to `Equatable` being the scenes.